# Alternative to multiple or statements in an if block in Javascript

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic

I have to check for

```
if(x == "An" || x == "Apple" || x == "A" || x == "Day" || x == "Keeps" || x == "The"....and so on){
      return true;
}
else{
     return false; 
}
```

Is there a better way to write the `if` statement for large number of `||` conditions?

Comment: A `switch` statement would be more structured, and keeping the target strings for the compare in an array would be tidier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matches = ["An", "Apple", "A", "Day"];
if (matches.indexOf(x) > -1){
  return true;
} else{
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could store the values in an array and then check to see if `x` is in the array of values using [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4tu3fr5a/)

```
var values = ["An", "Apple", "A", "Day"];

if (values.indexOf(x) !== -1) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't do `if x then true else false` do simply `return x`. so:

```
var values = [...];
return values.indexOf(x) > -1;
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.

Answer (score -1):

I am no Java coder, so there may be syntactical errors, but I used the concept of what I would do in VB and then applied the syntax I found using uncle Google.

```
string[] SearchTerm = { "An", "Apple", "A","Day","Keeps","The" }
for(String str : SearchTerm){
    if(x==SearchTerm[i]){
        return true;
        break;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```